# How can I open VSC NeteaseMusic?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I open VSC NeteaseMusic? I have searched by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> with NeteaseMusic, but the result is:

> Please interact with document first otherwise play() will failed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Are you referring to https://github.com/nondanee/vsc-netease-music